# Does sip sip signalling part for webrtc call has to be encrypted as TLS?

Tags: webrtc, sip, tls1.2

If the signalling part of webrtc is handled by sip, is it mendatory that sip signalling has to be encrypted by TLS. Is it mendatory that sip over websocket has be encrypted as TLS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC uses TLS sessions or QUIC for its signaling transport – both are encrypted in nature. All other avenues for non-encrypted signaling don’t really exist in WebRTC. Theoretically they might work, but some browsers will either block them altogether or require the user to grant access to the camera and microphone on each interaction. Deploying anything serious to production with WebRTC without encrypting signaling for their browser implementations is not a real alternative.

WebRTC “forces” you to encrypt your signaling. What is left out of scope of WebRTC are things like authentication, authorization and identity management. You are free to do as you please in that domain – just make sure to do *something* here – and not leave this wide open for pranksters or worse.

For native applications on mobile, desktop or embedded – you can do whatever you like. That said, the mindset must be the same – mandatory encrypted signaling.

reference : [Best webrtc related blog](https://bloggeek.me/is-webrtc-safe/)

Comment: It looks to me nothing prevent a browser to use non encrypted signalling. (I do agree that this is not a good idea). The blog you refer seems to also indicate that encrypted signalling is optional.